# Always seeing Mirror image while capturing from Front Camera iOS 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

While capturing data from Front camera I am always getting Mirror image, how can I get what I am seeing in my preview window. I have set `videoMirrored` to be `TRUE`. Following is the code snippet:

```
AVCaptureConnection *lConnection = nil;

  for ( AVCaptureConnection *connection in [lHandle->m_output connections]) {
     for ( AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts] ) {
         if ( [[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
             lConnection = connection;
             break;
         }
     }
 }
if ([lConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
    [lConnection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
if ([lConnection isVideoMirroringSupported])
    [lConnection setVideoMirrored:TRUE];
```

Changing `setVideoMirrored` to `True/False` also doesn't change anything
(`isVideoMirroringSupported` returns Success)

Comment: I'm pretty sure your preview window should be showing mirrored video (in the sense of, as if you were looking into a mirror, so you raise your right arm and the arm on the right hand side of the display goes up) — when you capture data is it mirrored in that sense or is it mirrored compared to your preview window (and, hence, the right way around in terms of what comes from the sensor)?

Comment: Thanks Tommy.Can you tell me the reason why setting SetVideoMirrored to TRUE/FALSE doesnt change any thing.

Comment: Thanks @Tommy. Can you tell me the reason why setting SetVideoMirrored to TRUE/FALSE doesnt change any thing.

Comment: If I could I'd have posted an answer! I assume you've checked that `supportsVideoMirroring` is definitely returning YES?

Comment: @Tommy. Yes i Have checked isVideoMirroringSupported is returning YES, and tried to setVideoMirrored to YES/NO. but i have seen no change.

Comment: @RajatKothari Did you finally found a solution to this problem? I'm having the same problem with front facing camera.

Answer (score 9):

Flip the mirrored image with the following code.

```
UIImage * flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:picture.CGImage scale:picture.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];
```

Comment: This won't work if you take the picture in landscape.

Answer (score 3):

`Swift` version:

```
let flippedImage = UIImage(CGImage: image.CGImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: .LeftMirrored)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation()` to flip an UIImage.

```
// first get an UIImage from the front camera
let sourceImg = UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: 1.0, orientation: .leftMirrored)
return sourceImg.withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation()
```