# How do I implement .leftmirroring for an AVCaptureConnection while using front camera?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapture

I’ve been trying to build a custom camera based off of the Apple sample code project [Apple Camera Sample Project](http://%20https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AVCam/Listings/Swift_AVCam_CameraViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-Swift_AVCam_CameraViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_15) when using the front facing camera the photo is taken as mirrored. I’ve seen solutions which change the orientation of the picture after it is taken however I’ve heard that it’s possible to setup the AVCaptureConnection to take the picture with the property already set to `isVideoMirrored` to true as seen in the comment on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45401053/9367155 how would one go about implementing this solution in the Apple Sample code? Thank you